# psycopg2-binary installation into a virtual environment fails when trying to compile source code

Tags: django, pip, psycopg2

I am trying to install `psycopg2-binary` into my Django project. I am using a virtual environment and the command I'm running is

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

However, I'm getting a massive error message, the gist of it is this:

```
    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

**But, hey, I'm installing exactly 'psycopg2-binary'**

Why am I getting all this mess?

Comment: Platform/processor architecture? OS? Python version? Is Python 32- or 64-bit? (Please be careful, it's possible to run 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS.)

Comment: macOS, M1, Python 3.8, not sure how to find out whether it's 32 or 64-bit

Comment: I've now installed Python 3.10 from python.org, and it is 64-bit. Tried to install psycopg2-binary again, same result.

Comment: if you land here experiencing this problem, see [this github issue](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1286) for a test build of psycopg2-binary you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip cannot find you processor+OS at https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/2.9.2/#files so it tried to install from sources (the last file at the page) and failed.

Compiling from sources is currently the only way. If you can donate some spare processor cycles to the Psycopg2 authors they perhaps could start compiling and publishing wheels for OSX on M1.

Comment: Great, thank you, this makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem, except that I had been successfully installing this package on other instances.  What happened is they upped the version number of the package and the installer could not find it.  It was looking for 2.9.6, and when i forced version 2.9.5 it installed the binary without problem.

Answer (score 1):

For future searchers, a problem could be if you specify a version of the package that isn't compatible with your local Python version, e.g.:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
```

Using a Python 3.11 environment. The returned error could be the same. But if that's the problem, the install not specifying the version (or specifying a compatible version) should work. And of course, this is not specific to this package.